# Não consigo encontra o caminho do meu método GET no WebService Rest

Tags: java, rest

```
@Path("webservice")
public class WebService {

    private CriancaDAO criancaDAO = new CriancaDAO();

    @GET
    @Path("getCriancaTodasCriancas/{idCrianca}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Crianca> getCriancaTodasCriancas() {

        return criancaDAO.getCriancaTodasCriancas();

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/getCriancaPorId/{idCrianca}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Crianca getCriancaPorId(@PathParam("idCrianca") int idCrianca) {

        return criancaDAO.getCriancaPorId(idCrianca);

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/salvarCrianca/{name}/{sexo}/{dataNasc}/{parentesco}/{etinia}/{corCabelo}/{corOlhos}/{rua}/{bairro}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public String salvarCrianca(@PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("sexo") boolean sexo, @PathParam("dataNasc") Date dataNasc, @PathParam("parentesco") String parentesco,
            @PathParam("etinia") String etinia, @PathParam("corCabelo") String corCabelo, @PathParam("corOlhos") String corOlhos, @PathParam("rua") String rua, @PathParam("bairro") String bairro) {

        Crianca crianca = new Crianca();
        crianca.setName(name);
        crianca.setSexo(sexo);
        crianca.setDataNasc(dataNasc);
        crianca.setParentesco(parentesco);
        crianca.setEtinia(etinia);
        crianca.setCorCabelo(corCabelo);
        crianca.setCorOlhos(corOlhos);
        crianca.setRua(rua);
        crianca.setBairro(bairro);

        if (criancaDAO.salvarCrianca(crianca)) {

            return "(\"Crianca Salva!\")";

        } else {

            return "(\"Crianca não Salva!\")";

        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/salvarCrianca/{idCrianca}/{name}/{sexo}/{dataNasc}/{parentesco}/{etinia}/{corCabelo}/{corOlhos}/{rua}/{bairro}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public String AtualizaCrianca(@PathParam("idCrianca") int idcrianca, @PathParam("name") String name, @PathParam("sexo") boolean sexo, @PathParam("dataNasc") Date dataNasc, @PathParam("parentesco") String parentesco,
            @PathParam("etinia") String etinia, @PathParam("corCabelo") String corCabelo, @PathParam("corOlhos") String corOlhos, @PathParam("rua") String rua, @PathParam("bairro") String bairro) {

        Crianca crianca = new Crianca();

        crianca.setIdCrianca(idcrianca);
        crianca.setName(name);
        crianca.setSexo(sexo);
        crianca.setDataNasc(dataNasc);
        crianca.setParentesco(parentesco);
        crianca.setEtinia(etinia);
        crianca.setCorCabelo(corCabelo);
        crianca.setCorOlhos(corOlhos);
        crianca.setRua(rua);
        crianca.setBairro(bairro);

        if (criancaDAO.salvarCrianca(crianca)) {

            return "(\"Crianca Salva!\")";

        } else {

            return "(\"Crianca não Salva!\")";

        }

    }

}
```

Quando coloco o endereço do meu servidor:

http://localhost:8080/WebServiceAndroid/webservice/salvarCrianca/

Só da not found.

Prj no netbeans e servidor glassfish.

Comment: Você tá passando os parâmetros? Aliás, por que está enviando uma informação tão complexa via **`GET`**? Seria melhor usar o verbo **`POST`**.

Comment: Sim, estou e fiz assim porque segue um tutorial e o pouco que eu sei rs, ainda estou cursando a faculdade. Obrigado

Comment: Se quer uma dica: mude o tutorial ***=)***. Você vai acabar aprendendo errado.

Comment: Na anotação "@Path", faltou colocar o "/", deixe assim: "@Path("/webservice")", verifique também o que o @jbueno comentou, se não estiver passando os parâmetros não vai funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mais mesmo passando os parâmetros e colocando a @Path("/webservice") só da not found. Ex.:http://localhost:8080/WebServiceAndroid/webservice/salvarcrianca/marcelo/true/10-12-1991/pai/branco/castanho/castanho/walter/saofrancisco

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa também configurar teu web.xml. Ficaria assim:

```
<servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Aí você vai conseguir acessar a url assim:

```
http://localhost:8080/WebServiceAndroid/rest/webservice/salvarCrianca/
```

Espero ter ajudado ^^